# How to convert a list to a matrix?

Tags: r

In R i have an object k with type "list":

```
> k
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "aa" "cg" "cg" "tt"
[2,] "ag" "gg" "gt" "tt"
> dim(k)
[1] 2 4
> typeof(k)
[1] "list"
```

i would like to transform to a matrix p of character like e.g.

```
> p
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "aa" "cg" "gc" "tt"
[2,] "ag" "gg" "gt" "tt"
> dim(p)
[1] 2 4
> typeof(p)
[1] "character"
```

matrix() and as.matrix() don't seem to do the job. In fact, k is the result of a matrix() call applied tpo the result of a vapply()-call.

Comment: Could you use `dput` and paste the output ie. `dput(head(k))`

Comment: @akrun : the required output is `structure(c("aa", "ag", "cg", "gg", "cg", "gt", "tt", "tt"), .Dim = c(2L, 
4L))`

Comment: Thanks, You got some great answers from David Arenburg, agstudy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or

```
p <- as.character(k)
dim(p) <- dim(k)
typeof(p)
## [1] "character"
dim(p)
## [1] 2 4
```

Assuming this is `k`:

```
k <- structure(list("aa", "cg", "cg", "tt", "ag", "gg", "gt", "tt"),
               .Dim = c(2L, 4L))
```

Comment: Thanks David. This works when i do it by hand, but when i place these lines into a function

Comment: When i place the lines `p<-as.character(k)`, `dim(p)<-dim(k)`, and `p` at the end of my function after the creation of k, the output is again a "list of 8"

Comment: Try `p<-unlist(k), dim(p)<-dim(k)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use storage mode `storage.mode<-`.

Using David's data, `k`

```
k <- structure(list("aa", "cg", "cg", "tt", "ag", "gg", "gt", "tt"),
               .Dim = c(2L, 4L))
typeof(k)
# [1] "list"
storage.mode(k) <- "character"
typeof(k)
# [1] "character"
dim(k)
# [1] 2 4
is.matrix(k)
# [1] TRUE
dput(k)
# structure(c("aa", "cg", "cg", "tt", "ag", "gg", "gt", "tt"), .Dim = c(2L, 
# 4L))
```